# Any shortcut to do this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> How many numbers between `1` to, say, `100`, are divisible by `7` and not by `3`?

The only technique that I know of, is finding all the multiples of `7` between `1` to `100` and then just striking off those that are multiples of `3` as well.  Using this method, the answer I got is `10`.

Do you know of any shortcuts to do this?

Comment: What if you replaced $100$ by $100000000$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, exactly.  And that is why I seek a formula to do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to find the number of multiples of 7 and subtract the ones that are also multiples of 3.

You can find the number of multiples of 7 between 1 and $n$ by finding the quotient when $n$ is divided by 7 and discarding the remainder.  (We denote this as $\lfloor \frac{n}{7}\rfloor$, the greatest integer less than $n/7$.)

Then you can find the number of multiples of both 3 and 7 between 1 and $n$ by finding the quotient when $n$ is divided by $21$ and discarding the remainder, or $\lfloor \frac{n}{21}\rfloor$.

Thus the answer is $\lfloor\frac{n}{7}\rfloor - \lfloor\frac{n}{21}\rfloor$.  This works for any $n$!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the intuition behind why this works?  $7$ and $3$ would have many common multiples.  So, does this take care of this fact?

Comment: @J.Doe If a number is divisible by both $7$ and $3$, then it is also divisible by $21$.  $\lfloor n/a \rfloor$ computes the number of numbers less than or equal to $n$ that are divisible by $a$, so $\lfloor n/7 \rfloor - \lfloor n/21 \rfloor$ gives the desired result.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, it makes more sense now.  Thank you! :)